# 400 Response for asp.net web api POST request only when cors is enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, cors, http-status-code-400

I've been stumped on this one for a few days now.  I am a beginner to CORS so navigating this has been very confusing.

**What's going wrong:** I created a asp.net web api which can successfully send POST requests to my SQL database.  I have used POSTMAN to send the data successfully.  Once I enable CORS I can no longer send the data.  I receive a 400 Bad Request.

**Some References of my code:**

My Controller which handles the POST request:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using ClientsDataAccess;

namespace MS_Clients_Post.Controllers
{
    public class ClientsController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Client client)
        {
            try
            {
                using (NewlandiaEntities entities = new NewlandiaEntities())
                {
                    entities.Clients.Add(client);
                    entities.SaveChanges();

                    var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, client);
                    message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri +
                        client.Id.ToString());

                    return message;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My webAPIconfig.cs file (where I enabled CORS):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace MS_Clients_Post
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            //enabling cors.  The "*","*","*" attributes allow all to access.  This should be more limited acccess in the future.
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
            //end of cors code.

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm seeing in Fiddler:
[OPTIONS Response 200 (Only returned with Angular APP, not POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLYI4.png)

along with [POST Response 400 BAD REQUEST (With POSTMAN or Angular APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m18cm.png)

**TLDR;**
POST request using ASP.net Web API works before enabling CORS. Why doesn't it work after?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.  This was a failure to identify what was actually going wrong.  Couple different things:

- When my application was deployed by VSTS to my development webserver it removed the SQL server login credentials from IIS application.  (Advanced settings on IIS application pool).
- Secondly and more importantly, the Syntax of my Angular Application was indeed not correct.  Therefore the syntax was wrong from the Angular Application, but correct  from POSTMAN (in postman I would use a GET method to get the JSON from server, and copy-paste the JSON to do a POST request).

Lesson learned, if it says 400 Bad Syntax, double check the syntax of what you are sending!